# C# columns into array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to put each column into separate array. So that I can later select the category from combobox and show values. But I have no idea how to do this, I dont even know whether array is a good idea. Thanks in advance.

```
Category1    Category2       Category3
----------  ------------    ------------
  13            1              12  
  12            1              13
  12            5              14
  44            3              15
  23            6              16
```

I have tried something like this:

```
  if(char.IsNumber(s.Trim().ToCharArray().ElementAt(0)))
                {
                    double[,] p = new double[samples, columns];


                    for(int i=0;i<samples;i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
                        {
                            //p[i,j]=
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The data you have doesn't make sense.  Is category 1 related to category 2 and 3?  If so, are you sure both 13 and 12 relate to 1 in the second column?  More importantly, when you say you have no idea how to do this, what part, *exactly*, are you having a problem with?

Comment: Or are you saying you want them to select "category 1" and then you show all the values from that column?

Comment: Yes. These are just random vaules. I have big file with types and measurements in columns. I want to store them somehow and then select from combobox for instance Category1 (measurement type 1) and then use these values to show them or draw graph.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is to first create a class:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Category1 {get;set;}
    public int Category2 {get;set;}
    public int Category3 {get;set;}
}
```

Then create a list and populate it:

```
var categories = new List<Category> { 
                           new Category { Category1 = 13, Category2 = 1, Category3 = 12 },
                           new Category { Category1 = 12, Category2 = 1, Category3 = 13 } 
    };
```

Comment: Problem is that I don't know how many columns I will have. It may be different in different input files. Main problem is that I don't know how to read it and put it in array. I have added how i wanted to do this, but my idea looks stupid.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use list (unless the number of elements will remain the same and known)
Also you have not mentioned where are your reading this list from.
If its just a file convert it to some type of xml and parse it or just parse the text file. If db, then map the below classes to the db objects using ORM or just manually read them.

For your combo box
Create a class and parse the data into this class objects

```
class Category
{
  public string CategoryName {get; set;}
  public List<int> CategoryItems {get; set}
}
```

For combo box in your xaml have something like this

```
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding Categories}"
          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding CategoryName}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategoryIndex}"/>
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding CategoryItems}"/>
```

In your viewmodel for the binding this is how you would have it

```
public int SelectedCategoryIndex {get; set;}
public List<Category> Categories {get; private set;}
public List<int> CategoryItems
{
  get
  {
    return this.Categories[SelectedCategoryIndex].CategoryItems;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps